# Symfony Form Validation and Errors on Twig Template

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

I was searching for a solution for this issue for some time. I found a lot of questions on Stackoverflow and tried almost all but it is not helping me with my problem.

I've a form in the controller and twig view which will render the form. I also have an entity for validations.

```
/**
 * @Route("/buy", name="buy")
 */
public function buyAction(Request $request)
{
    $priceArray = $this->container->getParameter('price');
    $options = [];
    foreach ($priceArray as $billingCycle => $array) {

        $options[$array['description'].' $'.$array['price']] = $billingCycle;
    }

    $orderData = new OrderData();
    // $orderData->setNickName('Enter Server NickName');

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($orderData)
        ->add(
            'billingCycle',
            ChoiceType::class,
            array(
                'choices'           => $options,
                'choices_as_values' => true,
                'expanded'          => true,
                'label'             => 'Select Billing Cycle',
            )
        )
        ->add('nickName', TextType::class, ['label' => 'Nick name for your server'])
        ->add('ipAddress', TextType::class, ['label' => 'IP Address of your server'])
        ->add(
            'save',
            SubmitType::class,
            array(
                'label' => 'Proceed to Payment',
                'attr'  => [
                    'formnovalidate' => 'formnovalidate',
                ],
            )
        )
        ->getForm();

    $options = [
        'priceArray' => $priceArray,
        'form'       => $form->createView(),
    ];

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted()) {

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            die('form is valid');
        } else {
            $errors = $form->getErrors(true, false);
            dump($errors);
            exit;
        }
    }


    return $this->render('default/buy.html.twig', $options);
}
```

AppBundle/Entity/OrderData.php

```
    <?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class OrderData
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="missing_billingcycle");
     */
    protected $billingCycle;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="missing_nickname")
     */
    protected $nickName;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="missing_ipaddress");
     * @Assert\Ip(message="invalid_ipaddress");     
     */
    protected $ipAddress;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getBillingCycle()
    {
        return $this->billingCycle;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $billingCycle
     */
    public function setBillingCycle($billingCycle)
    {
        $this->billingCycle = $billingCycle;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getIpAddress()
    {
        return $this->ipAddress;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $ipAddress
     */
    public function setIpAddress($ipAddress)
    {
        $this->ipAddress = $ipAddress;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getNickName()
    {
        return $this->nickName;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $nickName
     */
    public function setNickName($nickName)
    {
        $this->nickName = $nickName;
    }
}
```

buy.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Purchase</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">

            {{ form_start(form) }}
            {{ form_row(form.billingCycle) }}
            {{ form_row(form.nickName) }}
            {{ form_row(form.ipAddress) }}
            {{ form_end(form) }}

        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

The form renders correctly. However, if I submit it, I am expecting the validation message to be visible on the page, but it is not visible.

```
$errors = $form->getErrors(true, false);
dump($errors);
```

This is showing me the validation errors translated. However, not quite sure what am I missing here so that it is not displaying on the view

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of digging, I found where I was wrong.

```
$options = [
        'priceArray' => $priceArray,
        'form'       => $form->createView(),
    ];

$form->handleRequest($request);
```

'form' assignment must be after the handleRequest

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
$options = [
        'priceArray' => $priceArray,
        'form'       => $form->createView(),
    ];
```

Comment: Thank you. We had the exact same problem